# After dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: my tabbar disappears

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4

I have an app which consists of three layers of view controllers: UITabBarController => UINavigationController => UIViewController. They are all generated in code rather than using IB. The tab bar is on the bottom as per the usual design guidelines. In my UIViewController I am using this code to present the modalViewController:

```
myModalVC = [[MyModalViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:myModalVC animated:YES];
```

This work fine and the modal view controller pops up and covers the entire screen.

However when a button is pressed within the modal view controller, I run this:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

And the modal view controller animates away. However I can see the original UIViewcontroller view but the tab bar disappears completely. I've googled a lot but I can't find anyone that has this same problem.

Comment: Do you observe the same behaviour when doing presentModalViewController on self.tabBarController ?

Comment: That doesn't show the modal View Controller at all. I've also tried self.navigationController.tabBarController presentModalViewController also which gain fails to show the modal VC.

Comment: You could use [self presentModalViewController:myModalVC animated:YES]; without going through the navigation controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I found this by googling a bit more. I made my tab bar controller a property of the app delegate and when it presents the modal vc, it does this

```
UIApplication *myApp = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
noIBAppDelegate*appDelegate = (noIBAppDelegate*)myApp.delegate;
[appDelegate.tabBarController presentModalViewController:myModalVC animated:YES];
```

Then it dismisses it by this bit of code

```
UIApplication *myApp = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
noIBAppDelegate*appDelegate = (noIBAppDelegate*)myApp.delegate;
[appDelegate.tabBarController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

This fixes the the tab bar disappearing.

Answer (score 3):

You should delegate your modal view controller to your parent view controller. `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` should be done by the delegate and not the modal view itself, parent view are responsible for dismissing the modal view.

Comment: I'll give you the answer as it pointed my in the right direction.

Comment: @Robert Redmond Not sure if that fixed your tabbar problem though

Comment: Thanks.  This fixed my extra space/gap appearing under the navigationBar.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
[self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: That doesn't dismiss the modal view controller unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer! I had the same problem, but I'm writing in Swift, so thought I'd include my solution that I figured out from looking at yours. I only had to use these two lines to fix the problem. Nothing else was needed.

```
tabBarController?.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

and

```
tabBarController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

I should also mention that the line: tabBarController?.delegate = self, is in the viewDidLoad function of my NavigationController.